# Get the first two distinct successors of a string from List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, string, list

Consider the following example

```
List<string> subList1 = new List<string>();    
subList1.Add("start");

List<string> subList2 = new List<string>();
subList2.Add("start");
subList2.Add("string1");
subList2.Add("string2");

List<string> subList3 = new List<string>();
subList3.Add("start");
subList3.Add("string3");
subList3.Add("string4");
subList3.Add("string5");

List<string> subList4 = new List<string>();
subList4.Add("start");
subList4.Add("string3");
subList4.Add("string6");

List<List<string>> mainList = new List<List<string>>();
mainList.Add(subList1);
mainList.Add(subList2);
mainList.Add(subList3);
mainList.Add(subList4);
```

So for search string = "start" , output = {"string1" , "string3"}
and for search string = "string3" , output = {"string4" , "string6"}

Also , the search string should never be a part of the output
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, where we will answer you programming question, no matter how specific.

Comment: Is there a golden rule you didn't mention. Why isn't the result for searching "start" equal to { "start", "string1" }. Is it the case that you need to search only stuff which differs from the "needle" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: If your lists can contain `null` values, then `FirstOrDefault` is not a good idea. Take one item instead and check if sequence is empty or not:

```
string search = "string3";
var query =
     mainList.Select(l => l.SkipWhile(s => s != search).Skip(1))
             .Where(l => l.Any()) // sequence should contain items after searched
             .Select(l => l.First())
             .Distinct() // select distinct results
             .Take(2); // take first two items
```

Output:

```
string4
string6
```

Solution is simple - from each sublist select all items after item you are looking for. If this produces non-empty sequence, then just select first item (that will be item successor of searched item) from this sequence.

Comment: @HansZ but I should select something when do projection

Comment: You should throw in a `Distinct()`

Comment: My linqs are a bit rusty, but can't you just .First and then eliminate the .Where?

Comment: @HansZ That would throw an exception if nothing was found

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm a bit late, I just wanted to mention one of the `Iterator` versions.
And it goes something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FirstNSuccessiveStrings(int n, string needle, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> lists, bool exceptIfNeedle = true) {

    bool afterNeedle = false;

    foreach (var list in lists)
        foreach (var @string in list) {
            if (afterNeedle) {
                if (exceptIfNeedle && (@string == needle))
                    continue;

                yield return @string;
                if (0 == --n)
                    yield break;
            }

            afterNeedle = @string == needle;
        }

}
```

That yields the following test results:

```
var x = FirstNSuccessiveStrings(2, "start", lists).ToArray();
// x is { "string1", "string3" }
var y = FirstNSuccessiveStrings(2, "string3", lists).ToArray();
// y is { "string4", "string6" }
```

But if you specify `exceptIfNeedle` to be `false` then `x` will become `{ "start", "string1" }`. I think that's a little misunderstanding with the question.